# Bundle command not found after install

Tags: ruby, bash, bundler

I used to use bundle install without encountering any errors, but suddenly I am getting 'bundle: command not found' when using bundle install.

gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.2 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/opt/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/opt/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/will/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/opt/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.0.0/libexec
     - /usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims
     - /Users/will/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/will/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - ~/bin
     - /Users/will/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/will/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims:/Users/will/.rbenv/bin:/Users/will/.rbenv/shims:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/Users/will/.rbenv/bin:/Users/will/.rbenv
/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/ruby-
enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin
```

which gem

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/gem
```

gem list bundle

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.12.5)
```

Comment: `rbenv rehash` not helping?

Comment: @IleEftimov Yea, not working.

Comment: Any chance that you installed rbenv, both with brew and by pulling from Githib?